# Drush, how to check migration rollback status

Tags: migration, rollback, status, drush, drupal-9

We are running a complex migration project that pulls data from various older DBs into our new staging website before we execute it on live.

For reasons, we have to rollback the migrations we have. I am using drush migration:rollback --group=xxxxx.

Unfortunately, this is a multi hour process, and the ssh connection timesout (running overnight). When logging back into the server, is there a way to check how far the rollback has gone? The process does not appear on htop.

I found a lot of references to check the drush migrate process, but no hits on Goolge (or elsewere) for a way to check how far the rollback has gone.

Thanks in advance

Comment: And importing a database backup from before the migration is no option?

Comment: Unfortunatelly not, because there are other aspects there, that we need to maintain